# Spring 3.1.2 MVC @ExceptionHandler with @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement a Spring Web MVC @ExceptionHandler with a @ResponseBody to return an object containing validation errors.  ([Strategy E documented here](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/)).

In Spring 3.0.x, there was a confirmed [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6902) , since resolved, that prohibited this from working properly.  I'm using Spring 3.1.2, and shouldn't be running into that one.

I am, however, running into an exception"Could not find acceptable representation".

Here's the exception:

```
[10/21/12 12:56:53:296 CDT] 00000045 ExceptionHand E redacted.loggi
ng.jdk14.LogWrapper error Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public 
redacted.model.view.ValidationErrorResponse redacted.controller.Re
stController.handleValidationException(redacted.util.ValidationExceptio
n,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Originating Class/Method:redacted.web.ui.filter.AccessControlFilter.pr
ocessFilter()

                                 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAccepta
bleException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessage
ConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMeth
odProcessor.java:115)
```

And here's the code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationErrorResponse handleValidationException(ValidationException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<ValidationError> errs = new LinkedList<ValidationError>();
    for (ObjectError er : ex.getErrors()) {
        errs.add(new ValidationError(er.getObjectName(), er.getDefaultMessage()));
    }

    return new ValidationErrorResponse(errs);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
@ResponseBody
public SearchResult search(@Valid @ModelAttribute SearchRequest searchRequest, BindingResult bResult) {
    if (bResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(bResult.getAllErrors());
    }
    return searchService.search(searchRequest);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You do have an Accept header of "application/json" right, if so can you please show how your ValidationException looks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading this you probably have some question about how I got this to work.  The short answer is that I don't know.  I reverted off my code and re-implemented (actually copy and pasted the controller bits) from here, and it suddenly started working.

If you're using Spring 3.1.2, @ExceptionHandler and @ResponseBody does work.

My tentative explanation as to why this didn't work initially was that it was probably a user error or an error in the (very complicated, this application is massive) deployment scripts I was uing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue when I needed to return a JSON error response for a request that ends with some known extension like "/blah/blah.xml". In this case Spring favors the extension-based representation matching, and ignores the Accept header (also is the case with the latest Spring 4.1.5).

I used the following to "lock" to the JSON response no matter what the request is.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that Spring Does not how waht to convert the  `ValidationErrorResponse` to, for example should it convert it to JSON, or XML or something else? try returning a ResponseEntity because you can control the content type directly.

```
protected ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorResponse> createResponseEntity(ValidationErrorResponse restApiError)
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

           // assuming your ValidationErrorResponse object has an http code stored in it
        HttpStatus responseStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(restApiError.getHttpStatus());
        ResponseEntity<RestApiError> result = new ResponseEntity<>(restApiError, headers, responseStatus);
        return result;
    }
```

I use something like in my application, also I have a bunch of RuntimeExceptions that I can throw which contain wihtin them enough information be able to generate proper error responses.

Comment: Is there a way to "default" or "lock" response representation to JSON?